# Is it possible to set a div or table completely stuck?

Tags: html, css, position

Just as my title says, is it possible to set a div or table stuck at the position it is. My problem is that I am using jquery to fade in an image but at the start the image is hidden, the title under the image flies to the top, but I want it to stay at the place it was..

Comment: Yes. Use position fixed. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
#example {
   position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <head>    
      <style type="text/css">
            div
            {
                position: fixed;
                // the left,down,right,top are used to adjust the location of your fixed div.
                left: 50px;
                down: 50px;
                right: 50px;
                top: 50px;
            }
      </style>
 </head>

 <body>
      <div>       </div>
 </body>
```